# Visual Studio 2015 Error ( An incompatible SQL Server Version was detected )

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

i need you guys help. I added a SQL Server Database to my asp.net project. However when i try to create a new table in the database, the error "An incompatible SQL Server Version was detected" come up.

I tried looking up online for solution and install the SSDT for it however it still do not work. I checked under "Extension and Updates", Microsoft SQL Server Update is not stated there too so I don't know what is going on... please help me experts. Currently using visual studio 2015 community version.

Comment: You tagged this question mysql. Are you using MySQL? The description of your question mentions only Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: my bad i confused with both of them. it should just be microsoft sql server not mysql

Comment: Is SQL Server installed and running?

Answer (score 0):

Try this--though it is hard to explain, and the actual details/location of information may vary depending on version, edition, installation, language, phase of the moon, etc. etc.

No guarantee this is your problem, but it--or something similar--is possible.

- Open the Properties for the database project
- There should be a set of tabs or pages. One of these is "Project Settings"
- There should be a dropdown labeled "Target platform
- Set this to the version of SQL you have installed/are trying to support.
- Attempting to attach a sample screen shot, below

Walking through that... I suspect this might not actually be your problem. Thing is, there are settings and switches similar to this in many places, and one of them is probably what you are looking for. Good luck!

[image]